# Counting occurences in Excel with particular conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a similar problem to one I had recently. But this one is quite a bit beyond my abilities. It's best to see the picture to see my problem.

I am trying to count unique numbers on a list, with particular conditions. I have a list of names of doctors who operate in either "strategic" or "tactical" mode. I want to assign them permanently to either of the two options (strategic/tactical), based on roles they've held in the past.
If they've ever been in strategic mode, I want the cell to return "strategic" while if they've only ever been in "tactical" mode, I want the cell to return "tactical".
If they've ever been in both, then they are assigned to "strategic".

Please see the attached picture. Please help. I really don't understand this clearly. I thought I was a super user. Not even close. Thank you to anyone who can help me with this.

[image]
Here is a picture of what is going on - you can see the challenge I'm facing. It's a lot more complicated this time around

Comment: @yass: Did you download the original image from the question and re-upload it? Please don't do that.

Comment: I used print screen and upload it

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following formula:
`=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8,"Strategic")>=1,"Strategic","Tactical")`

A2:A8 is Doctors column
B2:B8 is Role column
Countifs will count for each Doctor how many Role are Strategic
If the count is = > 1 => Strategic
Else Tactical

[image]